# Converted to mysqli and now my chart will not draw on HighCharts

Tags: php, highcharts

My stockchart used to work perfectly with mysql code.  I had to migrate to mysqli:

co2.php --- this reads the data from the db

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
//include ("utils.php");
// (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') 
include_once("JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();

$sqlChart_Q='SELECT mq2,unix_timestamp(timestamp) FROM example WHERE id > 57000 ORDER BY unix_timestamp(timestamp) ASC';
$sqlChart_R = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlChart_Q);

while($row = $sqlChart_R->fetch_row()) {
      $time=(int)$row[1]*1000;
      $mq2=(float)$row[0]; 
      $arrChart[]=array($time, $mq2);
   }
echo json_encode($arrChart);
$conn->close();
?>
```

and I get this:

> [[1589869534000,0],[1589880428000,735],[1589889504000,527],[1589896763000,488],[1589902200000,390],[1589905800000,399],[1589916709000,437],[1613929195000,33],[1613929195000,34],[1613929254000,35],[1613929254000,36]]

But the page that draws the chart simply comes up blank.  Here is its code.  Please help:

index4.php --- this is the sample code used for drawing the chart

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['uv', 'mq2','co2','temp'];

    /**
     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function createChart() {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },{},{},{}],

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {
        
        $.getJSON('http://myserver.com/highstock/examples/uvmq2/' + name + '.php', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data,
                yAxis: i
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                //add 4th
                //seriesOptions[i+1] = {
                //  name: '4th',
                //  data: data,
                //  yAxis: i+1
                //};
              createChart();
            }
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an image of the db data:[image: database]

And here is the server log entry.  But ive commented out the utils.php, why would it keep calling it?:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: include(utils.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/myserver.com/httpdocs/highstock/examples/uvmq2/temp.php on line 26\nPHP message: PHP Warning: include(utils.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/myserver.com/httpdocs/highstock/examples/uvmq2/temp.php on line 26\nPHP message: PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening 'utils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/myserver.com/httpdocs/highstock/examples/uvmq2/temp.php on line 26\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/vhosts/myserver.com/httpdocs/highstock/examples/uvmq2/temp.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/vhosts/myserver.com/httpdocs/highstock/examples/uvmq2/temp.php on line 30\n', referer: http://myserver.com/highstock/examples/uvmq2/index4.php
```

I just found this in the console.  The data looks fine:
[image: detailed jd console data]

Here is the log of seriesOptions.  co2 seems to be missing for some reason.  This could surely cause the issue of the chart not drawing.  The data is there, but for some reason the array received by index4.php is empty.  It shows up as [] with no data inside.  [image: seriesOptions array]

Here is a view at the arrays being logged. The first array is uv, the second array is empty as can be seen by [], the third array shown is uv, the fourth is the seriesOptions array which is missing co2, the fifth array is temp and then the last one is the seriesOptions again.
[image: arrays logged in console]

Comment: Hi @marciokoko, I have tried to reproduce the problem by using your code, but everything seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/he6bu0mq/ Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: Sure, what would you need me to add?  Is the resulting array being returned to the charting page in the proper format?  What else could I do to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How did the output of the old script look like?

Comment: I dont remember what the old output looked like, that was over 5 years ago, sorry.

Comment: As I mentioned above JS code with the recieved data looks good, but could you check if it is correctly fired in your environment? Is `console.log(data)` fired in `getJson` method? Also some check at the beggining of `createChart` function would be great (for example logging `seriesOptions`).

Comment: I just posted the browser console log, the array looks fine.

Comment: Why did I get 2 downvotes?!

Comment: I just added the log of seriesOptions.  I would come back as invalid reference fue to scope in the createChart function.  I had to log it right before i log data (the array).

Answer (score 1):

I DISCOVERED that it has to do with co2.php's variable type.  co2 reads a var called age and age is type INT in the db.  My code took all data and did a conversion using (float)$row[0].  So I had to change it to the right type (int)$row[0] and it now works perfectly.  Thanks to all!